# Docker and Postgres - Cannot connect to container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am attempting to start PostgreSQL in a docker container, but cannot connect from my terminal.

After running `docker-compose up -d` using the following docker-compose:

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.5
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 10m
        max-file: "3"
    ports:
      - '5416:5432'
    volumes:
      - ./api/db/postgres-test-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Running `docker ps` gives me:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE           COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                       NAMES
8611fc5a9a73   postgres:14.5   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   21 seconds ago   Up 12 seconds   0.0.0.0:5416->5432/tcp, :::5416->5432/tcp   api_db_1
```

But when I try to connect with `psql -h localhost -p 5416 -U postgres`, I get:

```
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5416 failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I had my VPN running. Disabling it fixed the issue.